# How to fix ng-bootstrap error 'this._toggleElement.contains is not a function'?

Tags: bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm using [ng-bootstrap NgbDropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown) as mentioned on that page. The dropdown works. I can see the drop down when I click it. But slowly the browser crashes.

Here is the error in the console. This error goes in a loop and then crashes the browser.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6. Very importantly, the app is running in a **web worker thread** using **platform-webworker**.

`products.html:6 ERROR TypeError: this._toggleElement.contains is not a function
    at NgbDropdown._isEventFromToggle (ng-bootstrap.js:3494)
    at NgbDropdown.closeFromOutsideClick (ng-bootstrap.js:3477)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (products.html:6)
    at handleEvent (core.umd.js:12079)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.umd.js:13540)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.umd.js:13128)
    at dispatchEvent (core.umd.js:8691)
    at Array.eval (core.umd.js:9302)
    at NamedEventEmitter.dispatchEvent (platform-webworker.umd.js:1926)
    at WebWorkerRendererFactory2._dispatchEvent (platform-webworker.umd.js:2032)`

UPDATE on 7/8/2017:

Seems this is a ng-bootstrap issue where the components wont run in the web worker thread. An [issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1666) has been created.

Comment: Can you give some code? Make sure you are including `NgbModule` in the imports section of your module.

Comment: I added some updates. I can see the drop down menu when I click it, but then slowly crashes.